# Java Observers/Object Listeners (Game Engine)

Tags: java

I'm working on a game engine, and the last question I had regarding this was what good way I can use to make "observers" or listeners. A user suggested that I should use Java's EventObject class to inherit from and make a Listener interface. However, this didn't provide me with good flexibility.

Here is the Handler annotation to state that a method is an event handler in a listener:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Handler {}
```

Here is the base class for Event, which is basically the same as EventObject (but I'll add abstract methods sooner or later):

```
public abstract class Event {

    private Object source;

    public Event(Object source) {
        this.source = source;
    }

    public Object getSource() {
        return source;
    }
}
```

Here is the Listener class, which is empty:

```
public interface Listener {}
```

Here is the ListenerHandler class, used to handle all listeners. You register and unregister them here. I'll edit the register/unregister methods later for a better use:

```
public class ListenerHandler {

    private ArrayList<Listener> listeners;

    public ListenerHandler() {
        this.listeners = new ArrayList<Listener>();
    }

    public void registerListener(Listener l) {
        listeners.add(l);
    }

    public void unregisterListener(Listener l) {
        listeners.remove(l);
    }

    public void onEvent(Event event) {
        for(Listener l : listeners) {
            Class<?> c = l.getClass();

            Method[] methods = c.getDeclaredMethods();

            for(Method m : methods) {
                if(m.isAccessible()) {
                    if(m.isAnnotationPresent(Handler.class)) {
                        Class<?>[] params = m.getParameterTypes();

                        if(params.length > 1) {
                            continue;
                        }

                        Class<?> par = params[0];

                        if(par.getSuperclass().equals(Event.class)) {
                            try {
                                m.invoke(this, event);
                            }catch(IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

From what I heard, it's a use of a lot of memory in order to get all methods of a class. I'm not going to assume this is the case, but I'm sure there is a better way as this will be a game engine with many components and such.

I'd like to know the best way to implement this, or if I'm doing it right. I'd also like to know if anyone can help me improve this in any way without hogging memory usage by the game (as of now it's not a big deal -- the "game engine" is not even close to rendering anything yet)

Comment: Is there any reason you simply don't use a `interface` to describe the event listener, rather than jumping through annotation hoops?

Comment: premature optimization is the root of all evil. make it work first, optimize later

Comment: I'm trying to understand why you use annotations here.
If you use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html you'll find it very easy to implement what you described without the annotations and all this dynamic analysis during run-time.

Comment: I'm really very interested in understanding your requirement. would you please elaborate more what are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: I want it as a way where events are triggered and sent through to a global method (which is in the EventHandler class) and then it's processed there. For example, the Player dies and it sends an instance of PlayerDeathEvent to onEvent. Any listeners registered with a method with the Handler annotation and which is "listening" for that event (e.g. the PlayerDeathEvent as the parameter) will be invoked.
Somehow I find it much better than just making XListener for every single event or object, which I find completely unnecessary.
Another example would be achievements.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to keep it a very simple example and will comment with different ideas to it:
First meet the Achievement class:

```
import java.util.Observable;
    public class Achievement extends Observable {
    public static class AchievementDetails {}
public Achievement() {
        addObserver(EventsListener.getInstance());
    }
    public void achievementReached() {
        AchievementDetails achievemetDetails = null;
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers(achievemetDetails);
    }
}
```

And then the events listener class:

```
import com.test.Achievement.AchievementDetails;
public class EventsListener implements Observer {
    private static EventsListener instance = new EventsListener();
    public static EventsListener getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        if(o instanceof Achievement) {
            AchievementDetails achievemetDetails = (AchievementDetails) arg;
            //do some logic here
        }
    }
}
```

The only one thing that is missing is to create an instance of your achievement (which register the EventsListener to itself) and handle the life cycle of it.

Comment: To enhance the code above, I would suggest to have an abstract class that would be parent to all of your events and a child of Observable class. This parent class would include an abstract method which returns an enum. The enum is include all possible types of Events. This is to enhance the code of the update method in the EventsListener to use switch instead of instanceof

Comment: I suggest to have a different event listener according to the action required. and register these listeners to the corresponding observable. for example, you may want to end the game in case of, death, timeout or for example server went down. In this case, you'll create a EndGameAction (Observer) and register this Action with all three Observables (DeathEvent, TimeOutEvent, and ServerIsDownEvent)

Comment: Would the way I'm doing it now a bad idea? I'm sure it's not as bad as it seems, but I'd like to know.

Comment: If registering an Observable to Observable will be hard to maintain and you need another solution, I think you need to take a look at Java Annotation Processing Tool (Java APT) here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/apt/ which in this case you may create your own compile-time annotation and process this annotation during compile time (using APT) and generate a java class that would register each Observable with its Obersver (linkage need to be put using annotation)

Comment: @Sparta I don't think that there's a good and a bad idea in such situations. Your code works fine. I'm just offering you another approach with different enhancements to it. The only thing to take care of in your case is that you also don't want to do a lot of processing during run-time as well. So, I suggest you take the annotation processing to compile time instead of run-time, if applicable.

Comment: By the way, the approach I'm offering dosn't use reflection at all even if used with APT. When using APT, you declare your APT class supporting special kind of annotations. Thus compiler filters class or methods before invoking your APT class.